# Set value for DataGridViewColumn just add to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a dataGridView. Now I want to add new columns to this and then set value for this columns.
This my code

```
DataGridViewColumn texBoxColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
texBoxColumn .Name = "River's name";
texBoxColumn .ValueType = typeof(string);
texBoxColumn .HeaderText = "name of river";
texBoxColumn .CellTemplate = cell;
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, texBoxColumn );
```

And then, I add value for this columns by query dataBase

```
 for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
        {
            dataGridView1[0, j].Value = "Hello";
        }
```

The problem is, this columns still null, don't show anything.
Any help? Thanks so much.

Comment: Your code does various wrong things; so, please clarify what you want to accomplish exactly: calling this code to populate the DataGridView1 (all the rows in column "River's name") from the data you have under the class riverData. This is the FIRST TIME the DataGridView is populated (no information on it). Is this what you want?

Comment: Dear Cong you would like to add new column right i mean there are already few columns? and you want to one more column. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: hi guys. I have an dataGirdView and it still have displaying data. Now I want add a new column for this gridView and want it displaying something I want like "Hello" for example.

Comment: Writing "Hello" in the new row `j` in the new column, `new_col`, is straightforward: `dataGridView1[new_col, j].Value = "Hello";` But your code doesn't do this; it takes the value from a different column (better: from column 1), what conditions the writing; also you are writing to column zero (first column everything), instead to the target column.

Comment: I insert it into column 0 or 1 or anything, It still not work. If I use the same code for another column (not just added) it show "Hello" for all of rows in column. But not work for this column just added

http://i.upanh.com/rcsxen

Comment: What you say does not make sense and, as said, your code depends upon factors we don't have any control on. If you want to get help quickly, write down easily reproduceable conditions (something anyone might write and get the exact behaviour you are getting); otherwise, you would have to find it by your own. Answer to the question, how to write "hello" to a given column/row has been answered.

Comment: Dear Cong it would help us to solve your problem easily if you can share the code with us.

Comment: There is a high chance that the `songlist.ten_song;` is empty. You should try some debugging. I'm sure this problem can be solved with a little debugging.

Comment: Hi guys, I just edit my code. And it still not working. Please help!